# Movimiento usuario entre dos puntos en Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo una pequeña duda, estoy haciendo una app para Android de una asignatura que tengo y consiste en que según la posición del usuario, se le recomienda un bar/restaurante cercano para ir a comer según ciertos parámetros que introduzca el usuario (radio, precio y calidad).

Hasta aquí todo perfecto, tomo la posición del usuario (latitud y longitud) y tomo la posición del bar (latitud y longitud).

Lo que me gustaría realizar es dibujar una ruta en el mapa entre la posición del usuario y la posición del bar restaurante, y que ha medida que el usuario se mueva, que se actualice su posición en el mapa hasta llegar a su destino.

He buscado por los diferentes posts de Stack Overflow algo de información y la que encuentro es algo difusa, o no sé aplicarla a lo que quiero hacer.

Si me pudierais ayudarme de cualquier manera, ya sea mostrándome algún post donde se hable de ello en el que yo no haya mirado o alguna página web donde ver información relativa a lo que estoy buscando que tampoco haya mirado, os estaría eternamente agradecido.

Comment: Quizás, en mi opinión, convendría que publiques la parte relevante del código que hiciste hasta ahora, con un comentario marcando el lugar donde llamarías a calcular la ruta (ya con las variables de cada punto declaradas), y en cambio de preguntar por recomendaciones (que serían basadas en opiniones), preguntar cómo sería la llamada a [Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). Además, ayudaría saber en qué lenguaje estás programando.

Comment: ya pusiste los marcadores de los bares en el mapa?

Comment: La cosa es que los datos que obtengo al calcular el bar más adecuado a las características introducidas por el usuario los guardo en una clase que he creado, a la cual se le pasa las distintas ubicaciones, el ido y e nombre del bar/restaurante. Una vez obtenido lo mando mediante un intent a la clase la cual va a ejecutar y mostrar lo obtenido en el mapa. Es decir, tengo que crear la clase entera.

Answer (score 1):

La primera opción:

1. Haz una petición para obtener los nodos de direcciones a la [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) y obtén la `overview_polyline`.
2. Decodifica el string utilizando [librería android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) con el método `PolyUtil.decode`.
3. Añade tus puntos decodificados al mapa:

   ```
   List<LatLng> decodedPoints = PolyUtil.decode(polylineString);
   PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
   options.width(6);
   options.color(Color.RED);
   options.addAll(decodedPoints);

   map.addPolyline(options);
   ```

La segunda opción:

- Utiliza una librería, yo he utilizado [Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary
  de akexorcist](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary), en lo personal me ha sido muy útil y es fácil de usar, solo le pasas los parámetros: el origen y el fin, el color, la ruta a pie o en auto, etc..

Respecto a que el marcador cambie cada vez que la ubicación cambia, si estas usando la FusedLocationProviderAPI puedes cambiar los marcadores en el método `onLocationChanged()`.

Comment: Muchs gracias René, en cuanto pueda lo pruebo y te comento por aquí. Un saludo.